# Text view not appearing in onDraw object

Tags: java, android, xml, android-canvas

I'm trying to get the text view '2' (in black) to appear in the centre of my view but for some reason it won't appear. Does anyone know what's wrong here and how this error can be fixed? Is there way of showing it and changing the colour of it programmatically rather than using XML?

**XML**

```
<com.apptacularapps.car.RectangleTextView
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:text="2"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#808080"/>
```

**Java**

```
public class RectangleTextView extends View {
    Paint paint;
    private TextPaint mTextPaint;


    public RectangleTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public RectangleTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public RectangleTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(1); // convert to dp?
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE); // delete line for filled rect

        mTextPaint = new TextPaint(TextPaint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mTextPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        mTextPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.drawText("2", 0, 0, paint);
        paint.setTextSize(20);

        int w = canvas.getWidth();
        int h = canvas.getHeight();

        int rectWidth = w/5;
        int space = w/15;
        int topRectHeight = getPaddingTop();
        int bottomRectHeight = getPaddingBottom();

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            int left = i * (rectWidth + space);
            int right = left + rectWidth;

            Rect rect = new Rect(left, 0, right, topRectHeight);
            canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);

            Rect rect2 = new Rect(left, h - bottomRectHeight, right, h);
            canvas.drawRect(rect2, paint);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have a paint object that defines how your text will be drawn and neither have you called canvas.drawText() in your onDraw() method. Do it this way:

```
    private TextPaint mTextPaint;

    private void init() {
    mTextPaint = new TextPaint(TextPaint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    // You can tweak the appearance of the textpaint here
    mTextPaint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
    mTextPaint.setColor(color);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw() {
    super.onDraw()
    // You can tweak the positioning of the text here
    canvas.drawText("2", 25, 25, mTextPaint);
    }
```

Comment: Can't I use the get width divide by 2 feature instead? I don't want to use exact pixel measurements as devices have different screen sizes.

Comment: Yup, you can use anything you want. I have just given an example there. You can compute the size of your canvas and place the view either at the center, any corner or some other place. Though make sure you are drawing it within the enclosing rectangle of the canvas and also consider any padding you may have applied.

Comment: What if I want a specific rectangle or 2 to be filled red?